# Paypal REST API - Duplicate invoice Id detected

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was getting this error even though I was using a unique invoice_number for each transaction request.But I don't understand why it is reporting a duplicate.

{"name":"DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","details":[],"message":"Duplicate invoice Id detected.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"8c24c538da594"}

Look at the Exception:-
[image]

Here The Code Of Building PAYPAL REST API:-

```
 var data_custom = new EzyWrap.Web.UI.Models.TransactionCustom
        {
            OrderId = orderId,
            StoreName = SiteSetting.Store.Name,
            Name = FirstName + LastName
        };            

   // Adding description about the transaction
        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            description = SiteSetting.Store.Name, //The store name 
            invoice_number = orderId, //Order Id that unique each paypal request
            amount = amount, //Cart Amount
            item_list = new ItemList()
            {
                items = itemList.items, //List of Cart Item
                shipping_address = shippingInfo //Shipping Information For Adddress
            },
            notify_url = notigyUrl,//Notify Url for IPN response
            custom = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data_custom),//Pass custom data of client information in json format
            reference_id = cart.FirstOrDefault().ReferenceNumber//Pass Reference Id Of the cart
        });

   this.payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = transactionList,
            redirect_urls = redirUrls,
        };

        // Create a payment using a APIContext
        return this.payment.Create(apiContext);
```

every time paypal refuses it due to the duplicate invoice. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code where you are building your API call request.

Comment: @ViKiG i add code just check..

Comment: I don't see when and how variable `orderId` is created.

Comment: @ViKiG when order is place on site.The unique order Id is generated and save to order table. So order id is unique sql auto increment Id.